# JavaScript how to discover asynchronous functions at breakpoint

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, debugging, asynchronous

I have strange problem in my work with JavaScript, where script doesn't work in Chrome real-time, but works if I break and continue at specific line.

The case: I have search box where I can search for items with specific name, and options to filter results by manufacture. Everything works fine in IE and Mozilla, but in new version of Chrome choosing a filter will empty the whole results **after half second delay**.

Code relies on JQuery and is too complex to post here (I haven't coded it and don't understand it well either), but I decided to ask if this kind of problem is specific to some known issue.

Here's an interesting fact. If I set at following line of code

`this.$el.find("#resultbox").show();`

and continue execution after breaking, everything seems to work normal. To me it seems like an asynchronous problem, where former method tries to do something asynchronously with some unknown function, and causes the problem if it's executed before that asynchronous function. Could this be the source of issue and how to track it in google chrome?

Comment: `new version of Chrome` Because it was working on older ones?

Comment: It was working before

Comment: It would be interesting if you could just provide a minimalistic sample (e.g a jsFiddle) replicating your issue

Comment: You're probably right when you say it has something to do with the async property of the feature. The searchtool will probably do a get request to your server, then updating the field it works on accordingly. As on how to debug this, go in the code. if it only does not work in Chrome, maybe it has something to do with the version of your jQuery.