# How to update fragmented JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, debugging, dependencies

With new version of Chrome, our shopping cart application stopped working, and we suspect that there's problem with the old JQuery library we are using. However, we are depending on multiple JQuery files as follows:

- jquery-ui.js
- jquery-corner.js
- jquery-corner.js
- jquery.js
- jquery-printElement.js
- jquery-spin.js
- jquery-tmpl.js
- jquery-waypoint.js

And we are not able to locate the cause of bug. We are using `yuicompressor` to compress our javascript libraries and application logic into a single file. Is our only choice to search and update all those files independently and hope to avoid conflicts, or does can I find these components in one package somewhere?

Comment: Does it show javascript/jquery errormessages in console/dev tool?

Comment: No, but there are some asynchronous problem with code. Here is thread describing the issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37162097/javascript-how-to-discover-asynchronous-functions-at-breakpoint

Comment: Well, with code that is too complicated and that you yourself don't understand, I would say, set up a test environment and see what happens when you update. If it doesn't work properly, contact a Javascript programmer.